# How to avoid ${props => props.myProp} in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, styled-components

How can we avoid to write `${props => props.myProp}` in *[styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)*?

For example, if we are styling a button:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background: ${props => props.background};
    color: ${props => props.color};
`;

render(
    <div>
        <Button
            background="red"
            color="white"
        >
            Example 1
        </Button>

        <Button
            background="black"
            color="yellow"
        >
            Example 2
        </Button>
    </div>
);
```

in the docs [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) and [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props) we need to write something like `${props => props.myProp}`. But this looks annoying and unnecessary.
Would be better if we could write just `${props.myProp}`.

My current workaround is to write something like:

```
const Button = styled.button`${props => `
    background: ${props.background};
    color: ${props.color};
`}`;
```

but this isn't clear and simple like using just `${props.color}`.

So, how can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper function that can be used anywhere you want to extract a prop from props:

```
const props = name => p => p[name];
```

Then use it like:

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background: ${props('bgColor')};
`;
```

Using `props('bgColor')` is about as close as you can get in syntax similarity to `props.bgColor` while still maintaining correct behavior.

If you want to be meticulous,you could create a variable instead of passing a string directly:

```
const bg = 'bgColor';
const Button = styled.button`
    background: ${props(bg)};
`;
```

---

As suggested by [mxstbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115623/mxstbr) in the comments, you might also like the [styled-props](https://github.com/RafalFilipek/styled-props) package.

Comment: You might also like the [`styled-props`](https://github.com/RafalFilipek/styled-props) package! :)